# Reverse proxy nil pointer

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to write a reverse proxy in golang that reuses the proxy but I'm getting a nil pointer for a reason that I can't see.

```
    type Configuration struct {
        Proxies map[string]Proxy `mapstructure:"proxies"`
        Port    int              `mapstructure:"port"`
}

type Proxy struct {
        Upstream   string `mapstructure:"upstream"`
        SkipVerify bool   `mapstructure:"tls-skip-verify"`
        HostProxy  *httputil.ReverseProxy
}
```

Those are the structs that I'm loading.  I then iterate through the map to create the ReverseProxy object int the proxy struct and start the service.

```
for host, proxy := range config.Proxies {
                log.Printf("Loading proxies for: %s", host)
                log.Printf("Upstream: %s", proxy.Upstream)
                log.Printf("SkipVerify: %t", proxy.SkipVerify)
                remoteURL, err := url.Parse(proxy.Upstream)
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse target: %v", err)
                }
                log.Infof("Remote : %v", remoteURL)
                proxy.HostProxy = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remoteURL)
                proxy.HostProxy.Transport = &http.Transport{
                        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
                        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                                KeepAlive: 15 * time.Second,
                        }).Dial,
                        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
                        TLSClientConfig:     &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: proxy.SkipVerify},
                }
                log.Print(proxy.HostProxy.Transport)
        }
        log.Info("Starting Up on Port", config.Port)
        http.Handle("/", &config)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.Itoa(config.Port), &config))
```

When it gets called I handle it like this:

```
func (config *Configuration) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        host := r.Host
        r.Host = r.URL.Host
        log.Info(config)
        if proxy, ok := config.Proxies[host]; ok {
                log.Infof("Processing request for %s", host)
                log.Printf("Upstream: %s", proxy.Upstream)
                log.Printf("SkipVerify: %t", proxy.SkipVerify)
                log.Print(proxy.HostProxy.Transport)
                proxy.HostProxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        } else {
                w.Write([]byte("403: Host forbidden " + host))
        }
}
```

But it throws exceptions that the proxy.HostProxy object is nil.  All the other data persists and logs correctly.  Such as the proxy.Upstream and the proxy.SkipVerify.

Comment: Please update your question with the stacktrace and the code it's pointing to.

Comment: ... nevermind, the `Proxies` is a map of **values**, not pointers, when you range over such a map, what you get in each iteration, is a copy of the value in the map, modifying the copy in the loop will not modify the original in the map. Change it to `Proxies map[string]*Proxy`. Or, after you're done initializing `proxy.HostPorxy`, you should set the `proxy` iteration variable into the map, overwriting the original, i.e. `config.Proxies[host] = proxy`.

Comment: ... here's an illustration of the above comment: https://play.golang.com/p/pw3Ek9xMekA

Comment: D'oh.  You're right, that was exactly it.  Thank you.